# What is the best way to combine the list and migrate to DTO layer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

I have whole list in tree structure ,

Category entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Category1.TABLE_NAME, indexes = { @Index(columnList = Category.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID, unique = true) })
public class Category1 {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "BB_Category1";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID = "pk_category_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_parent_category_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_MAIN_PARENT_CATEGORY_ID = "main_parent_category_id";
    public static final String USER_ADDED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_added_by";
    public static final String USER_MODIFIED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY = "fk_modified_by";
    public static final String COLUMN_MODIFIED_ON = "modified_on";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY = "BB_Product_category1";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID)
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", nullable = false)
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_MAIN_PARENT_CATEGORY_ID, columnDefinition = "INT(10)", nullable = true)
    private Integer mainCategoryId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    @Where(clause="status=1")
    private List<Category1> categories;

    @Column(name = USER_MODIFIED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    private int updatedBy;

    @Column(name = USER_ADDED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)
    private int createdBy;

    @Column(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_STATUS, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1", nullable = false)
    private int status;

    //@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) 
    //@ElementCollection(targetClass = Category.class) 
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = TABLE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = ProductService1.COLUMN_PRODUCT_ID))
    @Where(clause="status=1")
    private List<ProductService1> productService1;

    //Setter Getter

}
```

I get below Json Structure:

```
[
  {
    "categoryId": 60,
    "categoryName": "Category1",
    "categories": [
      {
        "categoryId": 61,
        "categoryName": "Category2",
        "mainCategoryId": 60,
        "categories": [],
        "updatedBy": 1,
        "createdBy": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "productService1": [
          {
            "productId": 61,
            "productName": "ProductP2",
            "productDescription": "111",
            "productNote": "111",
            "productPrice": 111,
            "productMaintenance": 111,
            "status": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "productService1": [
      {
        "productId": 60,
        "productName": "ProductP1",
        "productDescription": "111",
        "productNote": "111",
        "productPrice": 111,
        "productMaintenance": 111,
        "status": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> Category--->CategoryList--->ProductList--->ProductList

This is above what i have which is everything that i need , just want to combine the two product list's and merge to a single list and pass to DTO layer ,

My DTO class will be:

```
public class Category1Model {

    private String categoryName;
    private int mainCategoryId;
    private int updatedBy;
    private int createdBy;
    private int status;
    List<Category2Model> categoryList;
    List<ProductService1> productList;

    //setter Getter

}
```

expected Json format:

```
[
  {
    "categoryId": 60,
    "categoryName": "Category1",
    "categories": [
      {
        "categoryId": 61,
        "categoryName": "Category2",
        "mainCategoryId": 60,
        "categories": [],
        "updatedBy": 1,
        "createdBy": 1,
        "status": 1
      }
    ],
    "productService1": [
      {
        "productId": 60,
        "productName": "ProductP1",
        "productDescription": "111",
        "productNote": "111",
        "productPrice": 111,
        "productMaintenance": 111,
        "status": 1
      },
      {
        "productId": 61,
        "productName": "ProductP2",
        "productDescription": "111",
        "productNote": "111",
        "productPrice": 111,
        "productMaintenance": 111,
        "status": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What is the best approach to do this can i use recursion here ? any one please help me Thanks in advance.

As per the answer i update my question but still data is not mapped correctly , what changes i need to do please help me.

Here is my updated controller class

```
@GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<Category1Model> getCategory() {
            List<ProductService1> listOfAllProducts = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Category1> list =productCatService1.getCategory();
            int i=0;
            for(Category1 cat:list)
            {
                System.out.println("@%$#%$@%#%@$@%$$  "+i++);
           listOfAllProducts = getProducts(cat).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }

            return Category1Model.createModels(list, listOfAllProducts);

        }

        private Stream<ProductService1> getProducts(Category1 category) {
            return Stream.concat(category.getProductService1().stream(), category.getCategories().stream().flatMap(this::getProducts));
        }
```

Here is my method in DTO class where i can set the data to the dto layer :

```
public static List<Category1Model> createModels(List<Category1> entitys,List<ProductService1> productList) {
        List<Category1Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
        if (entitys == null || entitys.isEmpty()) {
            return models;
        }


        entitys.parallelStream().forEach(entity -> models.add(createModel(entity,productList)));

        return models;
    }


    public static Category1Model createModel(Category1 entity, List<ProductService1> productList) {

        if (entity == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Category1Model model = new Category1Model();
        model.setCategoryId(entity.getCategoryId());
        model.setCategoryName(entity.getCategoryName());
        model.setProductList(productList);
        model.setCategoryList(Category2Model.createModels(entity.getCategories()));

        return model;

    }
    }
```

Comment: So, you want one flat list of all results in `resultService1`, combining all nested categories? So category 1 would have product 1 and 2 while category 2 would have only product 2?

Comment: No , i want flat list that contains products in main category + products in sub category . i dont want to combine categories i just want to combine products in one list.

Comment: This is still not clear to me. You should make it clear in your question what exctly you need. For example, show us how your result structure should look like based on the JSON you gave (or is that how the result should look)? Also, this is not a [mcve], all those `updatedBy` and `status`, ... fields are irrelevant to this question I guess if your question is how to do recursion.

Comment: @g00glen00b i updated all the required info in question,please check ones Thank You in advance.

Comment: @g00glen00b  there ?

Comment: It's clear to me now. I've retracted my close vote and provided an answer as well. Though personally I think you should try to avoid the word "best" in "best approach" since that could be seen as opinionated. Also, the question can pretty much be simplified to a non-Spring (and even a non-Hibernate) question since it's mostly about recursion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150913/discussion-between-h36p-and-g00glen00b).

Comment: @g00glen00b Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking for the best approach would be based on opinions (which is off-topic for Stack Overflow). But a possible way of doing recursion to "flatten" those lists is by using [Java 8 streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

For example:

```
private Stream<Product> getProducts(Category category) {
    return Stream.concat(category.getProducts().stream(), category.getCategories().stream().flatMap(this::getProducts));
}
```

The `Stream.concat()` is being used to concatenate multiple streams together to one stream. In this case we use it to concatenate:

- The stream of products of the current category (`category.getProducts().stream()`)
- The stream of products of the next levels (this uses recursion)

The recursion happens in the second argument (`category.getCategories().stream().flatMap(this::getProducts)`). Basically we create a stream of child categories, and then map it to its products by calling the `getProducts()` method.

The reason why we're using `flatMap()` here is because `map()` would return a `Stream<Stream<Product>>` while, `flatMap()` merges all those streams to a single `Stream<Product>`.

---

Since this method will return a stream and not a list, you should collect it to a list somewhere by using:

```
List<Product> listOfAllProducts = getProducts(category).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for you are help but still data is not mapped correctly , dont know where is issue exactly I update in the question ill you please help me.

Comment: Hello I ask new question for that Please help me out .....Thanks in advance         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540564/data-is-not-mapped-correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try Jackson for JSON to Java object conversion. You might need simple annotations for serialization and de-serialization.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: actually i want to combine 2 productServiceList list's and merge it to another list and return that list to the DTO layer .

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use Hashmap for putting multiple objects into the DTO.

```
class CommonDTO{

private Map dataMap;//create getters and setters


}
```

Set commonDto as below

```
public CommonDTOsomeName()
{

CommonDTO commonDto=new CommonDTO();
Map dataMap=new HashMap();


dataMap.put(categoryList");
dataMap.put(productList");
commonDto.setDataMap(dataMap);

return commonDto;


}
```